# Camera preview stopped working after exit app

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8.1

In my Windows Phone 8.1 app I'm using `MediaCapture` class to display preview from front camera in created `Capture element`. I bind created `MediaCapture` object to Source properties of my Capture element and everything works fine, until application is run first time, if it's not then I get last view from camera before app was visible.

**Actions**
I've tried to handle application resuming/suspending events (similar like [here])[1](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/audio-video-camera/capture-photos-and-video-with-mediacapture) and dispose/create object inside them but as far as I see when I'm debugging my app this events don't do the thing because they are not fired.

Any ideas here?

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this article: [How to trigger suspend, resume, and background events for Windows Store apps in Visual Studio](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh974425.aspx)

> When you are debugging, Windows disables these activation events.
>
> [...]
>
> In the Visual Studio debugger, you can manually suspend, resume, and terminate your apps to debug process lifecycle events. To debug a process lifecycle event:
>
> 1. Set a breakpooint in the handler of the event that you want to debug.
> 2. Press F5 to start debugging.
> 3. On the Debug Location toolbar, choose the event that you want to fire